# Listen to Bottom sheet dialog fragment dismissal and open a new fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet, dialogfragment

I have a bottomsheetdialog fragment with 2 buttons on it. I'm opening it on `fragment1`.  On `button1` click, it should dismiss the dialog whereas on clicking `button2` it should first dismiss the dialog and then open a new fragment `Fragment2`. Right now I'm able to dismiss and move to `fragment2` but only problem is both the actions are happening at the same time. I want the dialog to dismiss first and then start the second fragment.

[image]

MY CODE:

**Fragment 1:**

```
 private var button2ClickListner = object : AcknowledgmentDialogFragment.AcknowledgmentCTAAction {
        override fun onContinueClick() {
           initializeFragment2()
        }

    }
    private fun showAcknowledgment() {
        AcknowledgmentDialogFragment = AcknowledgmentDialogFragment().newInstance(button2ClickListner)
        AcknowledgmentDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, AcknowledgmentDialogFragment.tag)
    }
```

**AcknowledgmentDialogFragment**

```
class AcknowledgmentDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private lateinit var binding: BottomsheetLayoutAcknowledgmentBinding

interface AcknowledgmentCTAAction {
    fun onContinueClick()
}

private lateinit var btn2: AcknowledgmentCTAAction

fun newInstance(btnContinue: AcknowledgmentCTAAction): AcknowledgmentDialogFragment {
    this.btn2 = btn2
    return this
}

private fun subscribeForUiEvents() {
    binding.button1.setOnClickListener({
        dismiss()
    })

    binding.button2.setOnClickListener({
        dismiss()
        btn2.onContinueClick()
    })
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.bottomsheet_layout_acknowledgment, container, false)
    subscribeForUiEvents()

    return binding.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(arg0: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0)

    dialog.window.decorView.findViewById<View>(android.support.design.R.id.touch_outside).setOnClickListener(null)
    dialog.window.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation
}
}
```

Comment: do you need to have a delay before `btn2.onContinueClick()` ? use this  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html

Comment: @fatemehfallahiarezoudar not exactly a delay. But I want it to listen to dismiss and then do the action `btn2.onContinueClick()`.

Comment: ok, have you tried overriding the onCancel method for BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Comment: like this ?    `override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface )
    {  btn2.onContinueClick();
        super.onCancel(dialog);
       
    }`

Comment: @fatemehfallahiarezoudar it does't help. still both the things are happening parallelly. Like dismissing the dialog and opening a new fragment. I did something like this. `binding.button2.setOnClickListener({ dialog.cancel() });` and then I added your code which is mentioned above.

Comment: @ASN could you solve the problem? If you could can you share solution please?